# Java files are missing in Master/Detail Flow (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I have a problem with Eclipse. When I want to start a new android project I only get xListFragment.java in my source folder. So, I'm **missing** the other 3 java files( detailActivity, DetailFragment, and ListActivity). **I have reinstalled** eclipse 3 times and updated and istalled all programms from scratch but still haven't got those files. If someone has an solution then please help me.

Best.

Comment: Have you ensured your ADT is up to date and has targets and samples installed?

Comment: Yes! That's what drives me crazy that I have updated the ADT and the DDMS and still no positive results.

Comment: Are you using the bundled "Mobile" Eclipse download with the ADT/Android SDK or are you manually configuring a stock Eclipse version with an external SDK and the Android plugin?

Comment: It's the bundled one.

Answer (score 0):

Until someone has a definite solution to post, here's a workaround. I had the same problem with Eclipse and the master-detail project. I tried multiple times creating the project and had those missing classes each time. To workaround the problem, I created a master-detail project in [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and copied over the missing classes and some bits of XML.